# C# Owin Self Host - Expected header 100-continue

Tags: c#, owin, katana, owin-middleware, http-status-code-100

We encountered problem using OWIN with selfhosting. We have webserver running from console application. **It is NOT running on IIS.**

HTTP 100-continue specification:
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.2.3

OWIN 100-continue specification: 
http://owin.org/html/owin.html

What/Where/How should handle **expect: 100-continue** header in Request? We are using simple bootstraper:

```
        string baseUrl = "http://*:8050/";
        var webApp = WebApp.Start<StartupConfiguration> (new StartOptions (baseUrl) { });
        string input = Console.ReadLine ();
        if (webApp != null) 
        {
            webApp.Dispose ();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to OWIN specification 100 (continue) responses are handled by server. In your case by OWIN.SelfHost.

100 (continue) responses are handled according to RFC2616 https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt

Notice that an origin server MAY omit a 100 (Continue) response if it has already received some or all of the request body for the corresponding request.

Comment: Thak you Radim for your answer. You are right. Device sent Expect: 100-continue header with only little data. We expected that this request should be far larger so we tried to make device send rest of data. Guys from Katana project told us that average implementation waits for about 300 ms for 100-continue response and then send data.